# How Can I get the root directory to the project programatically

Tags: c#, .net, string, path

I am trying to find a way to get the path to the very first / root directory of my project and haven't quite been able to despite many similar question on SO.

Comment: CurrentDirectory will be different if you're running unit tests FYI.

Comment: Call `GetParent` again?

Comment: @EricJ. that would be a problem then .. As I need this for the Unit Test.. Do you have any idea for  how can I do this during running unit test ?

Comment: Actually, the path may or may not be different depending on your unit test framework. Why not just check what it actually is in a unit test and create a little routine that removes that last part of the path for your specific environment?

Comment: Are you suggesting to trim the last part ? but wont that be a problem if say in a build server there are more than one last parts ?

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? If the goal is to, for example, read a file from the root directory, perhaps the file should be embedded and accessible from the code. With a bit more info on what's your goal we can provide a better answer...

Answer (score 1):

Each of `GetParent` and `.Parent` move you one step up the directory, so you can use `GetParent` or `.Parent` three times.

Comment: Not exactly. When running a unit test, your path is different (and at a different depth) than when running in Visual Studio.

Comment: @EricJ. hI ! , Is there a better approach for this or is this path I am on with a Limitation ?
Because I would need this path when running unit test